# what is the difference between ind. and indecl. in Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit

In [spokensanskrit.de](http://spokensanskrit.de), there are words that are marked as ind. and indecl.
For example, indecl. stands for indeclinable words in Sanskrit such as तावत्.
The same word is also marked ind. Could anybody tell me what this means and how is it different from indecl.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both mean the same: `ind.` or `indecl.` are both short forms of `indeclinables` - a class of words in sanskrit called `अव्ययम्` There's a verse about these

```
सदृशं त्रिषु लिङ्गेषु सर्वासु च विभक्तिषु । 
वचनेषु च सर्वेषु यन्न व्येति तदव्ययम् ।।
```

It is the same in all genders, case-endings and sentences. That which never changes is called **अव्ययम्**